# Adding event handlers to array of buttons does not work Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I am trying to assign event handlers to my buttons in an array. When I press the button, it should call a function but just doesn't and can't figure out why.
Here is my code:

```
var btns = [];
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_no mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_n mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_ne mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_o mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_c'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_e mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_so mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_s mvn'));
    btns.push($('<div />').addClass('mvn_se mvn'));
    for ( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].mousedown(function() {
            moveImage(this);
        }).mouseup(function() {
            clearTimeout(tMovement);
        }).mouseout(function(){
            clearTimeout(tMovement);
        });
        table.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').append(btns[i]);
        $($options.expose.elementMovement).empty().append(table);

    }
    alert($._data( $("div.mvn_so"), "events" ));
```

Once this piece of code runs, I click on the buttons and nothing happens. I even tried calling a dummy function that only had an alert in it and it still doesn't work. I also tried to get the event on a given element and it returns undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding the buttons to the DOM at all?

Comment: `push` method of `Array` javascript type returns the new length of the array. I am not sure on what object you call `addClass`.

Comment: @Igor - the `addClass` is acting on the jQuery object within the parenthesis of the `push`

Comment: right, miscounted the parenthesis

Comment: Try appending the buttons to the table before binding the event handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after hours of debugging, I finally found the culprit that was breaking my code. It was the goddamned `.empty()`
on `$($options.expose.elementMovement).empty().append(table);` when I removed it, the code worked just fine. I have no idea why it didn't work as it was but I am glad it works now. Even putting the empty in separate line breaks my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ADGSc/

```
$('#myTable').on({
    'mousedown': function() {
        moveImage(this);
    },
    'mouseup': function(something) {
        clearTimeout(tMovement);
        status.text('mouseup: ' + $(this).attr('class'));
    },
    'mouseout': function(something) {
        clearTimeout(tMovement);
        status.text('mouseout: ' + $(this).attr('class'));
    }
}, 'div');
```

This may not be *exactly* what you want, but hopefully it will lead you down the right path.

Learn more about jQuery's `.on()` function here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried it and still no luck. From my tests, my code just isn't adding handlers to the buttons.